# Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I'm trying to create an Alert class as follows:

```
@ObjectType()
export class Alert {
  @Field()
  status: 'error' | 'success' | 'warning' | 'info' | undefined

  @Field(() => [String])
  messages: string[];
}
```

However, it gives me the following error message:

> Error: Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system.
> You need to provide explicit type for 'status' of 'Alert' class.

Answer (score 8):

Create a type for `'error' | 'success' | 'warning' | 'info' | undefined` and add it to the field definition as such:
`@Field(() => StatusType)`

It's basically complaining that it can't infer the type of that field as it's not a primitive, whenever a field is an object or other user defined type you will need to provide type information like I've described

Comment: any idea if there's a way to do this with standard types? typegraphql seems to want everything to be as a  decorated @ObjectType() class. manually defining type throws an error in type checker

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to allow it as far as I can tell, but would be interested if you found a way to get standard types working for it

Answer (score 0):

my work around for the problem was an enum and tuple type.

```
//anything after EnumStatus is optional. depends on how much control you want.
type TSuccessArray = [EnumStatus.ERROR, EnumStatus.SUCCESS,EnumStatus.WARNING,EnumStatus.INFO,EnumStatus.UNDEFINED]

export enum EnumStatus {
        ERROR = "error",
        SUCCESS = 'success',
        WARNING = 'warning',
        INFO = "info",
        UNDEFINED = "undefined"
      }

    @ObjectType()
export class Alert {
  @Field(() => [String])
  status: TSuccessArray[];

  @Field(() => [String])
  messages: string[];
}
```

and somewhere in your code create a table or object with those options.

```
`const myArr:succesArray = [EnumStatus.ERROR, EnumStatus.SUCCESS,EnumStatus.WARNING,EnumStatus.INFO,EnumStatus.UNDEFINED]`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your tsconfig.json file

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```